# Link to pdf file using org-pdftools not working

Tags: org-mode, org-link, pdf-tools

I am using the following format in my org file `[[pdf:file_path.pdf][description]]` to link to the `file_path.pdf` file. When I click on the link I expect the pdf file to open. Instead, I get a dialog box with the question `No match - create this as a new heading?`

I am using Emacs 28.2 on Mac OS. `pdf-tools` is installed and I can see `PDF Tools` in the menubar when I open a pdf file. If I change the link to `[[docview:file_path.pdf][description]]` it opens the pdf in a `DocView` buffer as expected. My `org-pdftools` or `pdf-tools` setting doesn't seem to be working.

I followed the installation instructions from [org-pdftools](https://github.com/fuxialexander/org-pdftools) github page. An [issue](https://github.com/fuxialexander/org-pdftools/issues/93) on that github repo suggests using a [new package](https://github.com/org-noter/org-noter) but not sure what I should be trying.

---

More info:

`org-file-apps`:

```
Value:
((auto-mode . emacs)
 ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
 ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
 ("\\.pdf\\'" . emacs))
Original value was 
((auto-mode . emacs)
 ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
 ("\\.x?html?\\'" . default)
 ("\\.pdf\\'" . default)
```

`org-file-apps-macos`:

```
Its value is
((remote . emacs)
 (system . "open %s")
 ("ps.gz" . "gv %s")
 ("eps.gz" . "gv %s")
 ("dvi" . "xdvi %s")
 ("fig" . "xfig %s")
 (t . "open %s"))
```

`org-link-parameters`:
No value for pdf.

Comment: I would uninstall `org-pdftools` altogether and try the `[file:/path/to/file.pdf]` link. Does the PDF file get opened? How exactly - in Emacs or with an external application? With the `org-file-apps` settings above, it should open in Emacs - does it? Next question is: does it open with docview or with pdf-tools? Check the modeline to figure that out. Update your question with your findings. After that, we'll figure out what the next step should be.

Comment: Not using any prefix in the link works-- the pdf file is opened in emacs `pdf-tools` mode. That's what I need, so it's fine. I didn't get what your suggestion is exactly. I don't want to uninstall and reinstall things without a clear goal. I am baffled by why the documented suggestions are not working, and trying to see if there's something to learn here. PS: Several comments to which I replied seem to have been deleted, so re-editing the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and It worked (read the comments in the file).

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markus1189/org-pdfview/master/org-pdfview.el

Although this is not the optimal solution